# How to fix error code SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN when redirecting from another domain?

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I got my domain from GoDaddy, for `domain.app`. I currently have my SSL cert for both `domain.app` and `www.domain.app`. Due to issues regarding a mailer form, we needed to setup the Wordpress website in another hosting as a subfolder of the type `https://otherdomain.com/domainapp`, and configured a redirect from GoDaddy from `https://domain.app` to the subfolder (i.e. `https://otherdomain.com/domainapp`).

When accessing `https://domain.app`, I get the SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN from Firefox, what do I need to do to make this redirect work? Been trying for a while now.

**Update:** The domain `https://otherdomain.com` has its own SSL installed.

Comment: If `https://domain.app` redirects to `https://otherdomain.com/domainapp`, then the error can easily be from the `GET` request sent to `https://otherdomain.com/`. Since you only mentioned having SSL cert for `domain.app` and `www.domain.app`, what SSL cert are you using for `otherdomain.com`? *Hint:* An SSL cert doesn't last across a redirect. Sounds like you need to get another cert from GoDaddy, or am I misunderstanding what you're saying. If I am, please edit the question and clarify it.

Comment: Already updated it. I got a cert for `domain.app`, and the cert for `otherdomain.com` and `www.otherdomain.com`. I'm performing a redirect from domain.app to `otherdomain.com/domainapp`, where the website is stored.

Comment: When the web browser shows that error, it provides the ability to see the cert it got from the server, so you can see for yourself how it is wrong. Did you do that? Did you close and re-open the web browser and did you do a full refresh, to make sure you're not looking at cached information?

Comment: Already done that, same result.

Comment: What does "same result" mean what I told you to look at the extra information the web browser makes available, information you haven't provided before, so how can you not have different result (aka information) when you look for it?

Comment: Deleted cached information, re-opened the web browser, did a full refresh. Still get the same error I described. The error description lists 4 coded certs, but they dont match the ones stored in the other hosting.

Comment: Then that's your answer: Your cert hasn't been installed (correctly).